# is there a way to select two classes at the same time in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to select:

```
<tr class='odd-row'>
```

and

```
<tr class='even-row'>
```

at the same time using jquery, is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('tr.even-row, tr.odd-row')
```

You can also do

```
$('.even-row, .odd-row')
```

If you don't care that it's a tr.

You don't have to pre-mark the rows with an odd/even class. You can also do:

```
$('tr:odd, tr:even')
```

And jQuery will figure out which are odd/even on its own.

Comment: `$('tr:odd, tr:even')` evaluates to `$('tr')` :)

Comment: @Ariel I have a question about `$('tr.even-row, tr.odd-row')`. Is it going to be more efficient than doing `$('tr.even-row').something()` and `$('tr.odd-row').something()` separately?

Comment: @user961627 Yes, it will be more efficient, but it's not a huge difference, so if the code is clearer the other way do that since clear code is more important.

Answer (score 2):

like this (use a comma):

```
$(".odd-row, .even-row").something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multiple selectors. Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)